# How do I loop through a switch-case statement that asks for input again in c++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

First I am displaying a menu to the user in which they can make a choice from.
Once they make a choice, some code is executed and I want to show them the same menu again so they can make a different choice.

This is my code so far:

```
//call the menu function and put it in a variable which will be used in the switch case statements
menu_selection = main_menu();

condition_main = true;

while (condition_main) {    
    switch (menu_selection) {
        case 1: display(primes);
                menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 2: display(fibos);
                menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 3: display(primes_and_fibos);
                menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 4: display(primes_not_fibos);
                 menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 5: display(fibos_not_primes);
                 menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 6: search();
                 menu_selection = main_menu();

        case 7: condition_main = false;
                             return 0; //this exits the program
        default: cout << "\nThat is an invalid option. Please try again.\n\n";

    } 
}
```

When I run the program however, what seems to be happening is that if I choose option 1, it would do the code and the menu is shown again but if I choose option 1 again it would run the code designed for option 2. I have also tried a do while loop and not using a loop at all and nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're missing `break` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each case needs a break unless you desire to have one condition fall through to the next:

```
switch (menu_selection) {
    case 1: display(primes);
            menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 2: display(fibos);
            menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 3: display(primes_and_fibos);
            menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 4: display(primes_not_fibos);
             menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 5: display(fibos_not_primes);
             menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 6: search();
             menu_selection = main_menu();
            break ;

    case 7: condition_main = false;
                         return 0; //this exits the program
    default: cout << "\nThat is an invalid option. Please try again.\n\n";
            break ;
}
```

this [reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/53-switch-statements/) has more `switch` examples and also covers the falling through case as well.

As Steve suggested it also probably makes more sense to have the `return` after the `while` statement. This is would be the expected control flow and will most likely be easier to maintain as well. Moving the `main_menu` call out of switch into the loop will also make your code easier to change later on.

Comment: Moving the main_menu into the loop was great advice, thanks. It also helped me with a similar problem. And the reason I had return 0 in case 7 was so that I can tell the program to close or would making condition_main = false achieve the same thing?

Comment: @John Yes, if you replace the `return 0` with `break` then when it goes back to the top of the `while` loop `condition_main` will be `false` and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 3):

I agree, the break is missing.  You might want to consider a code structure more like this: *(my formatting isn't great because I was going for compact)*

```
do {
   menu_selection = main_menu();
   switch (menu_selection) {
   case 1 : display(primes);            break;
   case 2 : display(fibos);             break;
   case 3 : display(primes_and_fibos);  break;
   case 4 : display(primes_not_fibos);  break;
   case 5 : display(fibos_not_primes);  break;
   case 6 : search();                   break;
   case 7 : break;
   default: cout << "\nThat is an invalid option. Please try again.\n\n";
} while (condition_main != 7);
return 0;
```

(formatted the way you prefer, of course.) This has only a single call to the menu function, making maintenance much easier.  The `return` is also at the end of the function, where most people expect to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `break`s will 'fix' the problem.

However, it would be better to separate out the code to make it easier to test. You might have realised the problem yourself then.

Separate your input and your handling code:

```
bool handleSelection(int menu_selection) {
    switch (menu_selection) {
        case 1: display(primes);
        case 2: display(fibos);
        case 3: display(primes_and_fibos);
        case 4: display(primes_not_fibos);
        case 5: display(fibos_not_primes);
        case 6: search();
        case 7: return false;
        default: cout << "\nThat is an invalid option. Please try again.\n\n";
    }
    return true;
}

void pump() {
    int menu_selection = main_menu();
    while(handleSelection(menu_selection)) {    
        menu_selection = main_menu();
    }
}

int main() {
    //pump();
    handleSelection(3);    
}
```

You should probably separate the output code, too (*"That is an invalid option. Please try again"*), but I think I've made my point without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean condition = true;
while(condition==true){
System.out.println("Press Number \n 1 for check prime \n 2 for exit");
Scanner scannerOption = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = scannerOption.nextInt();

    switch (option){
        case 1:
            checkPrime();
            break;
        case 2:
            condition = false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Enter plz try again");

    }
}
```